# For loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that recursively goes through files in a directory, writing the file's name and hexdump to a file. My current script:

```
#/bin/sh
touch hexdump.txt
for filename in logical/*; do
    echo "$filename"
    "$filename" >> hexdump.txt
    hd /logical/"$filename" >> hexdump.txt
done
```

The current output is:

```
logical/*
./hexadecimalExtraction.sh: line 5: logical/*: No such file or directory
hd: /logical/logical/*: No such file or directory
```

How do i get it to interpret "logical/*" as the list of files within "logical" directory and not the filename itself???

Comment: Looks like your `logical/` directory is empty. What does `printf '%s\n' logical/*` say?

Comment: Where is this "logical" directory"? `logical/*` will look for it (and files inside it) under the current working directory, but with `/logical`, the leading "/" will make it look at the top level of the filesystem instead. The difference matters.

Comment: add a `[[ -f "$filename" ]] || continue` after the do, maybe?

Comment: likewise, if you find `logical/fileX` your call to `hd` is going to try to operate on `/logical/logical/fileX`. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

```
"$filename" >> hexdump.txt
```

should probably be removed

Otherwise you are trying to run the filename itself.

Also you are looking for files in logical subdirectory in the current directory, but the trying to look in /logical/

Answer (score 0):

You can't recurse with `for filename in logical/*`. In order to recurse, you have to use `find`.
To make find visit only files, not directories, use `find -type f`.
I don't know hd, but you probably want

```
find tutorials -type f | while read i; do
    echo $i >> hexdump.txt
    hd $i >> hexdump.txt
done
```

Comment: ... you have to use `find` *or a recursive function which calls itself on  each directory.*

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `**` glob operator.

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for filename in logical/**/*; do
    echo "$filename"
    hd "$filename"
done >> hexdump.txt
```

`filename` will contain the full name of the matched files, which already includes the directory `logical` and any sub directories.